# Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning, CentOS, SmartGit, SmartSvn

Tags: java, jvm, smartgit, smartsvn

On running the shell script provided with SmartGit,

```
  Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: You have loaded library /home/User/.smartgit/6/jna-tmp/com/sun/jna/linux-i386/libjnidispatch.so which might have disabled stack guard. The VM will try to fix the stack guard now.

  It's highly recommended that you fix the library with 'execstack -c <libfile>', or link it with '-z noexecstack'.
```

Although it opens up fine, on doing a commit I get,

```
java: cairo-misc.c:380: _cairo_operator_bounded_by_source: Assertion `NOT_REACHED' failed.
smartgithg.sh: line 100:   394 Aborted                 $_JAVA_EXEC $_VM_PROPERTIES -Xmx${SMARTGITHG_MAX_HEAP_SIZE} -Xverify:none -Dsmartgit.vm-xmx=${SMARTGITHG_MAX_HEAP_SIZE} -jar "$SMARTGIT_HOME/lib/bootloader.jar" "$@
```

On researching up a bit, I found,

1. 64 bit library should be used. (if this is the cause please tell me how to do it).
2. Correct JRE isnt found. Downloaded a new JRE and gave its path inside the shell script. Same warning and crash.

what could be causing this, and how do I fix it?

Comment: Just updated Centos and now I'm getting this also. Also had the same issue with Eclipse. Turning of the cairoGraphics via the eclipse.ini file did the trick there. So I imagine this is also a graphics display issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On the subject of the preventing the SmartGit 6.0.7 crash on opening the commit dialog, as a work-around I modified the smartgithg.sh to add `-Dorg.eclipse.swt.internal.gtk.cairoGraphics=false` to the Java command. i.e. changed the command to:

```
$_JAVA_EXEC $_VM_PROPERTIES -Xmx${SMARTGITHG_MAX_HEAP_SIZE} -Xverify:none -Dsmartgit.vm-xmx=${SMARTGITHG_MAX_HEAP_SIZE} -Dorg.eclipse.swt.internal.gtk.cairoGraphics=false -jar "$SMARTGIT_HOME/lib/bootloader.jar" "$@"
```

I found this work-around, for another item of software based upon Eclipse, described at http://e2e.ti.com/support/development_tools/code_composer_studio/f/81/t/379466.aspx

[I have also sent this information to syntevo support]

Answer (score 0):

Same than above for `SmartSvn in smartsvn.sh`

> $_JAVA_EXEC $_VM_PROPERTIES -Xmx${SMARTSVN_MAX_HEAP_SIZE} -Dsmartsvn.vm-xmx=${SMARTSVN_MAX_HEAP_SIZE} -Dorg.eclipse.swt.internal.gtk.cairoGraphics=false -jar "$SMARTSVN_HOME/lib/bootloader.jar" "$@"